# Как исправить скрытие списка?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

1. Как сделать, чтобы при клике на дочерний ul список скрывался также, как и при клике вне списка? Cейчас, например, нажимаем на факториал в "Мат. выч", а список заново открывается. Хочется, чтобы при клике на факториал список закрывался, а открывался заново при нажатии на "Мат. выч".
2. Как можно оптимизировать еще код, а то получается немного быдловато?

   jsfiddle.net/foxt4bu4/1
3. Как сделать активным пункты "Мат. выч, Объем или Площадь", когда на них нажали?

Answer (score 1):

1. События click и события mouseup абсолютно разные, поэтому останавливая одно, вы не останавливаете другого. Поэтому вместо события `$(document).mouseup(function (event){ ... })` используйте `$(document).click(function (event){ ... })`.
2. Можно разом повесить все события, чем делать это для каждого. А еще лучше сделать это все на чистом CSS.

   ```
   $(document).click(function (e){ 
       var btn = $("#menu ul");
       if (!btn.is(e.target) ) {
           $("#menu > li > ul").each(function(){ $(this).slideUp() }); 
       }
   });
   $("#menu > li").each( function(){ 
       $(this).click(function(e){ 
           $("ul",this).slideToggle();
           e.stopPropagation();
       }) 
   })
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/nrxxLrvL/
3. Добавить класс выделения и дальше при клике выдавать этот класс. Например, дописать рядом toggleClass

Comment: Минус в том, что, если мы нажимаем сразу и на Мат. вычисления, и на Площадь, и на Объем, то открываются сразу все, а так не должно быть. Если открываем одно, то закрывается другое.